# How to display only 1 item in C# google org chart?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have created the following chart using google organisation chart but I have some problems. When I open the page or when I refresh the page it shows up the full chart like in picture below. But I want only the items that are in red square to be shown how can I do this.

I do not want to get a few items from the list but when I open the page it shows the whole chart with its all list item and instead when it opens I want to display only 5 items and let user to expand others do you understand me?

This is the picture of chart how it looks like and how I want it to be!

[image]

And here is my full c# code:

```
namespace OrganizationChartUsingGoogleAPI.OrganizationChart
{
public static class ConvertTo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the object type in the given type and handle the DBNULL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to convert</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">value</param>
    /// <returns>converted value and if DBNULL then return the type's default value i.e. string = string.Empty, Int16=0 </returns>
    public static T CastIn<T>(this object value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value)
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(string.Empty, typeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }


        if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToInt32(value), typeof(T));

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}

public partial class OrganizationChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Get the List name to fetch the data from
    string listName = "OrgChart_Demo";
    int iRowCounter = 0;
    string sAllNewRows = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fetch the data (recursively) from the list
        GetNode(string.Empty);

        //Generate the Client Script and Register
        GenerateClientScript(sAllNewRows);
    }

    private void GenerateClientScript(string sAllNewRows)
    {
        string csName1 = "OrgChartScript";
        Type csType = this.GetType();

        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName1))
        {
            StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>");
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");


            cstext.Append("google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });");

            cstext.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");

            cstext.Append("function drawChart() {");
            cstext.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();");

            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Name');");                
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');");

            cstext.Append("var rowArr = new Array();");

           cstext.Append(sAllNewRows);

            cstext.Append("data.addRows(rowArr);");

            cstext.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
            cstext.Append("chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });");
            cstext.Append("}");
            cstext.Append("</script>");
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName1, cstext.ToString(), false);

        }

    }

    private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
        {
            //create a new row
            sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

            //Recursion
            GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
        }

    }

    private string createNewRow(SPListItem listItem)
    {

        //Converting list items to strings.
        string sName = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Name"]);
        string sTitle = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Title"]);
        string sMoreInfo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["MoreInfo"]);
        string sReportsTo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"]);

        //Checking if image field ref is empty or null (if it does't provide any img source link!)
        ImageFieldValue pageImage = listItem["Pageimage"] as ImageFieldValue;
        string sPicture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageImage.ImageUrl) ? "#" : pageImage.ImageUrl;


        StringBuilder sText = new StringBuilder();
        sText.Append("var NewRow = new Array();");

        //this row shows the image and everything else what chart needs
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '<img src =\"{1}\" style=\"width:57px; height:57px; float:left;\" />{2}<div style=\"color:white; font-style:Arial\">{3}</div>' }});", sName, sPicture, sName, sTitle));

        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sReportsTo));
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sMoreInfo));
        //sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sPicture));
        sText.Append(String.Format("rowArr[{0}] = NewRow;", iRowCounter));

        //Pageimage

        iRowCounter++;
        return sText.ToString();
    }

    private SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string destList, string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection ResultListItems = null;

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(destList);
                if (null == list)
                   return ResultListItems;

                string selected = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
              // Label1.Text = selected;

                //Check if the item already exist.
                StringBuilder sCAMLQuery = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Where>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<And>");
                if (reportsTo != string.Empty)
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                    //sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");

                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");

                }
                else
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<IsNull>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</IsNull>");
                }
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='Kompania' />");
                //sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + selected + "</Value>");

                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");

                sCAMLQuery.Append("</And>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Where>");

                SPQuery QueryResult = new SPQuery();
                QueryResult.Query = sCAMLQuery.ToString();
                ResultListItems = list.GetItems(QueryResult);
            }
        }
        return ResultListItems;          
     }              
   }
}
```

Thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a  GetNode(string reportsTo).

could you pass the level you're in and return if the level gets higher than you want?

```
private void GetNode(string reportsTo, int level)
{
    // maybe have some config or value you can set for the max level you want.
    if (level >= 2) return; 

    SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

    foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
    {
        //create a new row
        sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

        //Recursion
        GetNode(item["Name"].ToString(). ++level);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have also called this method `GetNode(string.Empty);` and i need to pass a level value, could i pass a 2?

Comment: I do not want to get a few items from the list but when I open the page it shows the whole chart with its 50 item and instead whet it opens I want to display only 5 items and let user to expand others do you understand me?